# Stochastic Sequence; Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_n)n≥1$ be a stochastic sequence of i.i.d. random variables, each
$X_n$ with values in the set {1, 4, 8, 16} and probability distribution:

$P[X_n = 1] = 1/6, P[X_n = 4] = 1/4, P[X_n = 8] = 1/3, P[X_n = 16] = 1/4$.

Compute $lim_{n→∞}(X_1 ·X_2 · · · X_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. [ Hint: Transform the expression whose limit is to be computed
such that the ergodic theorem or the law of large numbers can be applied ]

How can i compute $lim_{n→∞}(X_1 ·X_2 · · · X_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Or how can i transform the expression so that the ergodic theorem or the law of large numbers can be applied?

Comment: Hint: the logarithm was invented as a way to convert multiplication into addition.

Comment: What does $\lim_{n\to\infty}(X_1X_2\ldots X_n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ mean in this context? Are you quoting the question correctly? If this is some sort of homework, please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag and read the tag wiki.

Comment: @whuber ok thx i will look into that.

Comment: The question is much more interesting when "$1/2$" is replaced by "$1/n$" :-).

Comment: @whuber yeah sorry you were correct. There was a mistake. Unfortunately  I overlooked it. It is 1/n not 1/2.

Comment: @whuber because that's the correct question.^^ Sorry for any inconveniences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using $\log_{2}$:**

$$
   lim_{n→\infty}\log_{2}\Big((X_1 ·X_2 · · · X_n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} \Rightarrow lim_{n→\infty} \frac{1}{n} 
    \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_{2}(X_k)
$$

**Using Ergodic Theorem:**
$$
  lim_{n→\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_{2}(X_k) \Rightarrow \sum_{x\in X} \log_{2}(x)v(x)
$$

$$
\log_{2}(1)*\frac{1}{6} + \log_{2}(4)*\frac{1}{4} + \log_{2}(8)*\frac{1}{3} +\log_{2}(16)*\frac{1}{4} = \color{blue}{\frac{5}{2}}
$$

**Applying Inverse function:**

$$
2^{\color{blue}{\frac{5}{2}}} = \color{red}{5.659}
$$